# Plot various cases using R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to visualize health insurance benefit options for my company to help others make a decision. I have a table like so:

```
| plan |        ded |  oop | exp_oop |
|------+------------+------+---------|
|    a |        400 | 2100 | 17400   |
|    b |       1300 | 2600 | 14300   |
|    c |       2600 | 5200 | 28600   |
```

- `ded` = deductible; expense level where 90% co-insurance kicks in
- `oop` = out of pocket maximum
- `exp_oop` = amount of medical expense at which `oop` is reached

I want to plot cost to the employee vs. medical expenses incurred. Health insurance works in ranges...

```
cost = expenses for 0 < expenses < ded
cost = deductible + (0.10 x (expenses - ded)) for ded <= expenses < exp_oop
cost = oop for oop <= expenses <= infinity
```

How might I plot each of these ranges? Basically, one gets a line of slope = 1 for 0 to each plan's deductible, then a line of slope = 0.1 from x = deductible to x = oop, and then a line of slope = 0 from oop upward.

I'm not sure how to conditionally plot with ggplot2. If you'd like to use the above, here's reproducible code for these cutoffs:

```
dat <- data.frame(plan = c("a", "b", "c"), ded = c(400, 1300, 2600), oop = c(2100, 2600, 5200), exp_oop = c(17400, 14300, 28600))
```

Do I have to create the x/y values myself? In other words an intermediate table like so?

```
| plan |     x |    y |
|------+-------+------|
|    1 |     0 |    0 |
|    1 |   400 |  400 |
|    1 | 17400 | 2100 |
|    2 |     0 |    0 |
|    2 |  1300 | 1300 |
|    2 | 14300 | 2600 |
|    3 |     0 |    0 |
|    3 |  2600 | 2600 |
|    3 | 28600 | 5200 |
```

I'm doing this for several variants (employee only, employee + spouse, etc.) so it would be great if I didn't need separate data tables for each plan but could just work with the already defined deductibles and out of pocket max values I already have in a data frame...

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Sounds like you want to write a custom function to calculate expenses based on the rules you describe, and then use that function to calculate cost on a range of `x<-0:some high value` for each plan, probably using `apply` or similar.

Comment: From your description, it seems that the boundary between the second and third tier should be `exp_oop`, not `oop`.

Comment: @BrianDiggs Fixed -- good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach basically follows [Drew's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13074716/892313), but just does the steps differently. I start with a function which takes the `plan`, `ded`, `oop`, and `exp_oop` and returns a function which gives a cost for a given expense (based on those parameters). [Note: I've assumed the break between the second and third tier is `exp_oop`, not `oop` as originally stated in the question.]

```
cost_generator <- function(ded, oop, exp_oop, ...) {
  function(expenses) {
    ifelse(expenses < ded, 
           expenses, 
           ifelse(expenses < exp_oop, 
                  ded + (0.1 * (expenses-ded)),
                  oop))
  }
}
```

Now using `plyr`, I can create a list of functions which map expenses to cost, one for each plan

```
library("plyr")
funs <- mlply(dat, cost_generator)
```

For each function, determine the cost for a given range of expenses. Here, I've picked a range from 0 to $50,000 in increments of $100.

```
pts <- ldply(funs, function(f) {
  expenses <- seq(0, 50000, 100)
  data.frame(expenses=expenses, cost=f(expenses))
})
```

This gives a data frame in long form which is easy to plot.

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(pts, aes(expenses, cost, colour=plan)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Of course, this is not really cost, but amount paid out of pocket for a given level of expense. Total cost will include additional things (premiums, at least).

EDIT:

If you want to make sure every change point is included (not relying on rounding to the nearest $100), you can extract the points from `dat` and use those:

```
library("reshape2")
exps <- melt(dat, id.var="plan")$value
exps <- c(0, exps, 1.1*max(exps))

pts <- ldply(funs, function(f) {
  data.frame(expenses=exps, cost=f(exps))
})
```

I added 0 and something larger than the largest value in the table to make the ends reasonable.

[image]

Comment: I like it. Thanks. Can you explain what `function(f)` does? I don't see any references to `f`... Also, this will be slightly inaccurate to the nearest 100, correct? There's no way to target slope changes at the actual values for those changes without making my sequence incorporate said x values, right?

Comment: `function(f)` declares and anonymous function which takes as its sole argument a function (named `f` inside the anonymous function). That function is called in the creation of the data.frame (`cost=f(expenses)`).

Comment: Thanks for clarification on the function (haven't gotten into this at all in my learning of R). Re. the second part of my question, I hunted around and believe I can generate my sequence from the data itself: `sort(plot[!duplicated(plot$x), "x"])`. Those are the only x values that matter for the plot I'm trying to make. Neat stuff.

Comment: By the way, looks like you're missing a closing `)` after `pts <- ldply ... cost = f(exps)) }`. Thanks for the update; I missed that bit as the answer. My comment above won't actually work; I was working with the intermediate table above, which was the whole point in asking this question (not having to manually do that), so thanks for the added solution.

Comment: @Hendy Thanks for catching the missing parenthesis; must have been a cut-and-paste error. I've fixed the answer now.

Comment: 'Nother question. I have some additional column names in `dat` now so that I can cycle through the various plan types (employee-only, employee+spouse, etc.). The `funs <- ...` line throws an error unless I add all column names to the definition of `cost_generator` even though they remain unused. Can I do something like `cost_generator <- function(names(dat)) ... ` in order to make it robust to whatever column names are present in `dat`? The actual variables used for calculation will remain the same.

Comment: And to be clear, `ldply` takes the `funs` data.frame and *appends* expenses and cost? I was surprised to see that the result of `pts <- ...` included all the original data as well as your calculated column since it didn't really reference the original data... except for `funs`

Comment: You can change the declaration of `cost_generator` to `function(ded, oop, exp_oop, ...) {`... and it can take as many other variables as exist in the `dat` data.frame. I've updated my answer with this change. `funs` is a list, not a data.frame. If you just print out `funs`, you will see that it has an attribute `"split_labels"`. This is something `plyr` maintains behind the scenes. Since you used `dlply` to create `funs`, the details of the data.frame that was used is stored along with it, and when you then transform back to a data.frame (with `ldply`), that information can be restored.

Comment: My point was moreso that if I tweak my data frame, I have to manually add the variables to `function(list, of, variables...)` or it complains. Since I won't change the definition of the actual function but might re-use other vectors in the data.frame later, I wondered if there was sort of a "catch all" definition of all the names in the df I could pass.

Answer (score 1):

Write a vectorize function to calculate costs to the employee as a function of expenses occurred. It must be vectorized, so that you can feed it to `ddply`.

```
costFinder <- function(df, oopActual) {
  #df is your 'dat'; we will throw away exp_oop
  #oopActual should be a vector; it is the x axis of your plot
  ded <- df$ded
  oopMax <- df$oop
  cost <- rep(NA, length(oopActual)) #preallocating with NAs will help ID mistakes
  cost[oopActual<ded] <- oopActual[oopActual<ded]
  cost[ded <= oopActual & oopActual < oopMax] <- 0.1 * (oopActual[ded <= oopActual & oopActual < oopMax] - ded) + ded
  cost[oopMax <= oopActual] <- oopMax
  return(cost)
}
```

Then define an `expense` seqence (not too many data points, or it becomes computationally expensive) and calculate the actual out-of-pocket cost foe each value of expense, for each plan:

```
expense <- seq(0, 50000, by=200)
allCosts <- ddply(dat, .(plan), costFinder, expense)
names(allCosts)[2:ncol(allCosts)] <- expense
```

Now melt the vector so you can use it with `ggplot`. Here, I employ the shady trick of renaming the columns of the allCosts data frame with numerical values. This is probably a bad idea, and I'd love to see a better way to do it.

```
costsM <- melt(allCosts, id.vars="plan") 
names(costsM)[2:3] <- c("expense", "actualOOP")
#melt() interprets the column names as a factor. We have to turn them back into numeric,
#    by turning them into characters first and then numerics.
costsM$expense <- as.character(costsM$expense)
costsM$expense <- as.numeric(costsM$expense)

#Plot the data
p <- ggplot() + geom_line(data=costsM, aes(x=expense, y=actualOOP, colour=plan))
print(p)
```

[image]

```
#Add vertical lines for the expected OOP, if you like - arguably it makes things more confusing.
p + geom_vline(data=dat, aes(xintercept=exp_oop, colour=plan))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. More complicated than I thought. I might just be better off calculating with a spreadsheet and using csv? I created one manually, and I believe something is off with your graph. The three segments should be slope = 1, slope = 0.1, slope = 0 with no big jumps. The blue line jumps drastically for some reason. Take a look at [my version](http://i.stack.imgur.com/d8eaU.png). Is this just an image scale thing, or is something not quite right with yours? (Disregard the dotted lines; those just show adjusted costs based on premium savings and company HSA contribution.)

Comment: There may be a mistake in the way I encoded the costFinder function.